# Old Oracle (non-ansi) join syntax for more complex join conditions (Oracle 12c)

Tags: sql, oracle, olap

I am creating a  WITH ROWID, on-commit fast refresh materialized view and as I understand it, Oracle requires the query that defines the mview to use non-ansi (old oracle) style joins. I have a join that I dont know how to convert to old oracle join, and that the inbuilt Oracle conversion tool doesn't handle correctly.

Consider EMP as

| EmpID | Department |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Retail |
| 2 | Retail |
| 3 | Corporate |
| 4 | Corporate |
| 5 | Corporate |

and OVERHEAD as

| EmpID | Overhead |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $10 |
| 2 | $20 |
| 3 | $100 |
| 4 | $120 |
| 5 | $220 |

I am trying to denormalize for olap, so I want to do something like this

| EmpID | Department | CorpOverhead |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Retail | null |
| 2 | Retail | null |
| 3 | Corporate | $100 |
| 4 | Corporate | $120 |
| 5 | Corporate | $220 |

In ANSI I know how to do this, and get the result I want:

```
select 
   EMP.EmpID, 
   EMP.Department, 
   OVERHEAD.Overhead as CorpOverhead
from EMP
left join OVERHEAD on 
   OVERHEAD.EmpID = EMP.EmpID 
   and EMP.Department = 'Corporate'
```

In old Oracle, I am stumped. The sqldeveloper tool to toggle between join methods gives me this

```
select 
   EMP.EmpID, 
   EMP.Department, 
   OVERHEAD.Overhead as CorpOverhead
from EMP,
   OVERHEAD 
where 
   OVERHEAD.EmpID(+) = EMP.EmpID 
   and EMP.Department = 'Corporate'
```

which results in

| EmpID | Department | CorpOverhead |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Corporate | $100 |
| 4 | Corporate | $120 |
| 5 | Corporate | $220 |

which is not what I want.

How can I write an old oracle join to accomplish the same as the ANSI join?

Comment: Why do you think that you have to use old-style joins? Can you include a reference to that restirction?

Comment: You must be wrong. I can't imagine Oracle requiring their old join syntax for the materialized view. If you still want to rewrite the query: you don't need a join at all. You can simply put a subquery in your select clause.

Comment: @AlexPoole in deed that's an Oracle bug. Oracle requires old join syntax for FAST refresh MViews.Well, when I created a case for that long time ago, it was only considered as a "lack of documentation" not as a bug. As far as I know, it is still not solved but meanwhile (for Oracle 19 and newer) I could be wrong.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it's a bug, see above.

Comment: @AlexPool Here is one source. Like you all are saying, I banged my head against the wall on this one until I found it in unofficial documentation. It would make sense that it's a bug.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4492244/why-mv-refresh-fast-on-commit-is-not-possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression in the `JOIN`:

```sql
select e.EmpID, 
       e.Department, 
       o.Overhead as CorpOverhead
from   EMP e,
       OVERHEAD o
where  CASE e.department WHEN 'Corporate' THEN e.EmpID END = o.EmpID (+)
```

Which, for your the sample data, outputs:

| EMPID | DEPARTMENT | CORPOVERHEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Corporate | 100 |
| 4 | Corporate | 120 |
| 5 | Corporate | 220 |
| 1 | Retail | *null* |
| 2 | Retail | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QorJ-lLS)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest also laterals:

```sql
select e.EmpID, 
       e.Department, 
       v.CorpOverhead
from   EMP e,
       lateral(
         select o.Overhead as CorpOverhead
         from OVERHEAD o
         where e.department='Corporate'
           and e.EmpID = o.EmpID
       )(+) v;
```

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/6IPbC4eE

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` will eliminate all rows that don't fit the `WHERE` clause

If you want to exclude values ,you  ueed a `CASE WHEN`

```
select 
   EMP.EmpID, 
   EMP.Department, 
   CASE WHEN EMP.Department = 'Corporate' THEN   
   OVERHEAD.Overhead ELSE NULL END as CorpOverhead
from EMP,
   OVERHEAD 
where 
   OVERHEAD.EmpID(+) = EMP.EmpID
```

I really don't want to know how old your developer is as `JOIN`s are literary 30 Years in sql standard

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you wanted to do it just with joins then you'd need to use a subquery:

```
select 
   EMP.EmpID, 
   EMP.Department, 
   OVERHEAD.Overhead as CorpOverhead
from EMP,
   (
      select
         OVERHEAD.EmpID,
         OVERHEAD.Overhead
      from EMP,
         OVERHEAD
      where 
          OVERHEAD.EmpID = EMP.EmpID 
          and EMP.Department = 'Corporate'  
   ) OVERHEAD 
where 
   OVERHEAD.EmpID(+) = EMP.EmpID
```

It would be simpler, and perhaps more logical, to move that condition to a case expression in the select list:

```
select 
   EMP.EmpID, 
   EMP.Department, 
   case when Emp.Department = 'Corporate' then OVERHEAD.Overhead end as CorpOverhead
from EMP,
   OVERHEAD 
where 
   OVERHEAD.EmpID(+) = EMP.EmpID
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5synXimj)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that kind of problems with queries not accepted by MV FAST REFRESH - even I never got the ANSI-join related one but some others (WITH clauses and other funny ones..) - I now always create a standard VIEW with all the required columns for the FAST REFRESH and then create the MV as "select * from mv_basis_view", and later I have an other VIEW on the MV without the unnecessary columns for the "business" use.
This pattern often solves the problem, more extreme problematics have to be solved by "cutting" the original MV into 2 (or more) MVs, and doing the desired job on them in standard VIEWs (with the correct indexes on the intermediary MVs it remains quite efficient). Of course, millage may vary according to DB version.
Note also that you can often get the old-style JOIN query from the ANSI-style one by using DBMS_UTILITY.EXPAND_SQL_TEXT: it may save you some headache.

Comment: dbms_utility.expand_sql_text was my first thought too, but interestingly it gets it wrong by losing the outer join. https://dbfiddle.uk/EY9-qs0V